# How to sign up with google in pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you go to the menu of pokemon go for the first time to create your account, it normally says "Sign up with google", then pokemon trainer club and then privacy policy, but for me there is no option for signing up with google. I've tried to sign up with trainer club but that won't work. I've tried changing my google age, uninstalling and installing go and creating a new account but none of that works. What should i do?

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot of the screen that doesn't show signing in with google? Also what device are you using?